# counting each value in dataframe

Tags: pandas, plotly, python-3.6

So I want to create a plot or graph. I have a time series data. 
My dataframe looks like that:

[df.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV6EB.png)

I need to count values in `df['status']` (there are 4 different values) and `df['group_name']` (2 different values) for each day.
So i want to have date index and count of how many times **each** value from `df['status']` appear as well as `df['group_name']`. It should return Series.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I used `spam.groupby('date')['column'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)` and it working as it should. Thank you all for help